# I can't approve and sell a token I bought on pancakeswap. I saw someone else sell it in the transaction list on bscscan

Tags: transactions, bsc, pancakeswap

Okay, so obviously I bought a scamcoin, but theres this one guy who still managed to sell it, most likely by using a bot. I want to sell the token as well, the liquidity isn't pulled and I would make a nice amount of money. Here's the information I have so far.
The unsellable token that got sold anyways:
https://bscscan.com/token/0xe7878bcddd112ec9e2131c542fd9e7284bc85359

The buyer who was able to sell the token:
Buy: https://bscscan.com/tx/0x9af6bd647a2a8e160a6215d38b1f5b1a9aca219674d24fd8938369969aa458bf
Sell: https://bscscan.com/tx/0x0dd5f37f94d5abd5a7792e3841bb32eed8c2813bfba549f22a56c6ac34154903

I am sure he used some kind of bot, because the token received liquidity at 08:43am and 24 seconds, the token was bought at that exact same time as well. 8 minutes later, the token was sold.

The contract that was used was based off this token:
https://bscscan.com/address/0x32c4b5d79e44aa7594fac11c0b6d7f61f3ae6429#code
the only difference is the amount of coins and address that is allowed to sell.

I remember a guy who made a website called swaphelper, it was a bot that helped you sell these kinds of unsellable tokens. The bot worked, but apparently he took it down.

Finally, if someone manages to find a solution I will give him a part of the money I earn from selling the scamcoin

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123108/discussion-on-question-by-scammeddude-i-cant-approve-and-sell-a-token-i-bought).

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange! This question was flagged. If you're trying to write a token that people cannot sell, please don't do that. Otherwise be careful what tokens you are buying: there might not be people here with the time to figure out what these tokens are doing.